# Radio button's value attribute is only allowing numbers

Tags: html, radio-button

I am experiencing something weird with radio buttons, and I'm hoping someone here can explain to me what is happening.

I have created a radio button like so:

```html
<input type="radio" name="radio-smoker" value="true" />
```

When I load the page in the browser (Chrome), and inspect the radio button I see:

```html
<input type="radio" name="radio-smoker" value>
```

The value attribute has no value.

However, when I change the value from "true" to "1", the value attribute works and the value "1" is retained.

I also noticed that if I set a value of "test1", I end up with a value of "1". It seems to strip out the letters, only allowing numbers.

I have tried to recreate this elsewhere (e.g. jsBin), without success. It only happens in the one place.

What is happening, and where can I begin to find out what's causing it?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. Inspect the element and you can see the value isn't changed on runtime.

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="radio" name="radio-smoker" value="true" > True
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="radio-smoker" value="true1" > True1
</form>
```

Comment: AS you know `true` is a boolean value that cal also be 1 as `false` can be 0. You will never use this reserved word as a value. I don't know why you want to do it in this way. Possibly Chrome detect this and scrap it from your value attribute. So that sad don't make it to difficult for your self. Cheers :)

Comment: Naa. I'm not the one who wants to use it. I just showed to the guy that in my part, the value is not being strip out after running on chrome. I have even no idea why he wanted to use `true` or `1` as value. ISSET is available to check if the rb is selected though. @Franco

Comment: I am sorry but this comment was not for you, It is late in the night here and I had to post it under his question. So this is not a comment about what you wrote

Comment: "it works" is never an answer. At best it's a comment.

Answer (score 0):

After some investigating, it turns out there was a jQuery mask plugin setting a number mask on all inputs of the page. Thus why only numbers were allowed. Once that was removed, all radio button values started working as intended.